# How to rewrite thid XML file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I trying to rewrite this xml file containing this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrowserAutomationStudioProject>
     <ModelList>
          <Model>
               <Name>token</Name>
               <Description ru="token" en="token"/>
               <Value>5660191076:AAEY8RI3hXcI3dEvjWAj7p2e7DdxOMNjPfk8</Value>
          </Model>
          <Defaults/>
          <Model>
               <Name>chat_id</Name>
               <Value>5578940124</Value>
          </Model>
          <Defaults/>
     </ModelList>
</BrowserAutomationStudioProject>
```

My python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Actual.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for model in root.findall('Model'):
    name = model.find('Name').text
    if name == 'token':
        model.find('Value').text = '123456789:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    if name == 'chat_id':
        model.find('Value').text = '1234567890'

tree.write('xml_file.xml')
```

It works but I get the same file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrowserAutomationStudioProject>
     <ModelList>
          <Model>
               <Name>token</Name>
               <Description ru="token" en="token"/>
               <Value>5660191076:AAEY8RI3hXcI3dEvjWAj7p2e7DdxOMNjPfk8</Value>
          </Model>
          <Defaults/>
          <Model>
               <Name>chat_id</Name>
               <Value>5578940124</Value>
          </Model>
          <Defaults/>
     </ModelList>
</BrowserAutomationStudioProject>
```

What's wrong with my code?
Even ChatGPT can't help me haha
I even tried to print it but it doesn't work
What I should do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the documentation, [Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are **direct** children of the current element.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements). You need to force ET to [selects all subelements, on **all levels** beneath the current element by using `//`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).

Since `<Model>` is not a **direct** child of root (it's a grandchild, or something to that effect :)), `root.findall('Model')` finds nothing. So to get ET to find it, you need to modify that to

```
root.findall('.//Model')
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `for model in root.findall('ModelList/Model')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of the xml tag you can do something like `pop()` the values from a list by iterate through the tree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Actual.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

input_value = ['1234567890','123456789:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']

for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "Value":
        elem.text = input_value.pop()
        print(elem.tag, elem.text)

tree.write('xml_file.xml')
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BrowserAutomationStudioProject>
  <ModelList>
    <Model>
      <Name>token</Name>
      <Description ru="token" en="token" />
      <Value>123456789:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</Value>
    </Model>
    <Defaults />
    <Model>
      <Name>chat_id</Name>
      <Value>1234567890</Value>
    </Model>
    <Defaults />
  </ModelList>
</BrowserAutomationStudioProject>
```